# How do I embed the Calandly widget into an Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, widget

I am trying to embed the [Calendly](https://calendly.com/) widget into an Angular app and am not quite sure how to accomplish this.  Since I will be calling this widget with variable data, I would like to invoke the widget with a user activated function.  Based on the documentation and [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55973983/calendly-widget-not-working-in-ie-angular-app) I have added the following method in my component:

```
getEventCalender() {
    Calendly.initInlineWidget({
      url: myVariable.url,
      parentElement: document.querySelector('.calendly-inline-widget'),
     });
  }
```

and call it with the following (in my .html)

```
<div>
  <button (click)='getEventCalender()'>view cal</button>
</div>

<div class="calendly-inline-widget"></div>
```

I can see that I need the `Calendly.initInlineWidget` method supplied by the .js api, however I'm not quite sure how to access it.  I have tried downloading the file and importing it into my component, however it didn't work (maybe I did this incorrectly).  I suspect this has something to do with the .js file not exporting the method, but not sure where to go from here.

Can anyone provide some direction?

Comment: Did you check the demo code : https://plnkr.co/edit/mpl6l8ifxc1amS611DMD?p=preview&preview

What are the errors in the console ? The best way to help you would be to provide a quick example. Try to build something here: https://stackblitz.com/ 

you can create an Angular App, import whatever you need and share it.

Comment: Thanks @gabrielstuff. Yes, I tried simply copying the Plunker code and the widget seems to function intermittently.  I get the below error:

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null
    at Iframe.Calendly.Iframe.Iframe.parseOptions (widget.js:550)
    at new Iframe (widget.js:530)
    at createInlineWidgets (widget.js:483)
    at widget.js:409
    at HTMLDocument.completed (widget.js:24)

Comment: I will build a plunker example and share...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar issue in our vanilla JS app and found the solution described in their [Advanced embed options](https://help.calendly.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020052833-Advanced-embed-options#1) documentation. We did this by:

1. Add `data-auto-load="false"` to the `calendly-inline-widget` `div`.
2. Add `parentElement` to the `initInlineWidget` function params.

---

Extra info: @remy-bartolotta we had the exact `split` error you described and the above info fixed it.

Comment: Thank you... this is relevant, however, in order to make this functional I needed to declare Calendly as a variable like so `declare var Calendly: any;`.  If this doesnt happen, the `initInlineWidget` method throws an error.  Thanks again for the info