# Angular: Dynamically added js not working after route

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular9

```js
//component 
import { ScriptService } from '../services/script.service';

constructor(private script: ScriptService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.script.load('calenderly').then(data => {
      console.log('script loaded ', data);
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

I tried integrating calenderly in one component which actually worked when i visit the page for the first time but when I revisit the page from other page (route) it doesn't works.

```js
//script store
interface Scripts{
    name:string;
    src: string;
}

export const ScriptStore:Scripts[]=[
    {name:'calenderly', src : 'https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js'},
   
]

//script.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ScriptStore } from '../models/scriptstore'

declare var document: any;
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ScriptService {

  private scripts: any = {};

constructor() {
    ScriptStore.forEach((script: any) => {
        this.scripts[script.name] = {
            loaded: false,
            src: script.src
        };
    });
}

load(...scripts: string[]) {
    var promises: any[] = [];
    scripts.forEach((script) => promises.push(this.loadScript(script)));
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

loadScript(name: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //resolve if already loaded
        if (this.scripts[name].loaded) {
            resolve({script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Already Loaded'});
        }
        else {
            //load script
            let script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = this.scripts[name].src;
            if (script.readyState) {  //IE
                script.onreadystatechange = () => {
                    if (script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete") {
                        script.onreadystatechange = null;
                        this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
                        resolve({script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Loaded'});
                    }
                };
            } else {  //Others
                script.onload = () => {
                    this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
                    resolve({script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Loaded'});
                };
            }
            script.onerror = (error: any) => resolve({script: name, loaded: false, status: 'Loaded'});
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        }
    });
}

}
```

```html
 <!-- Calendly inline widget begin -->
  <div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url="https://calendly.com/prince-shah97/15min" style="min-width:320px;height:630px;"></div>
  
  <!-- Calendly inline widget end -->
```

strong textI have added dynamic js to my controller using the reference from medium
"https://medium.com/better-programming/angular-load-external-javascript-file-dynamically-3d14dde815cb".
It worked but only when I refresh the same page but not when I go the the page from the other route(page).

Comment: Show us some code snippets please

Comment: Is the `load` method invoked anywhere? I think it's missing in your snippets. You have just shown the service from step1 of the medium article.

Comment: yes i call it from component whose html file is mentioned above to load the js

Comment: it works when i page is loaded initially but don't after i visit from other pages (route) it doesn't works

Comment: Could you show the typescript code of that component?

Comment: added..please check..

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code I think. Problem is calendly itself. Their script is nog smart enough to find dynamically added widgets so they assume it is there when the script loads. Therefore it works the first time. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55973983/calendly-widget-not-working-in-ie-angular-app/55975258#55975258

Comment: I check the example and i am not able to find about Calendly.initInlineWidget ({}) from where the Calendly ?